# URL REWRITE with & with out Query String

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Facing an issue while using with URLrewrite of tuckey..my requirement is like
    when the url contains dev/auth/dev/ what ever it comes after should be redirected to another url including query strings

ex: http://:8080/dev/auth/dev/student/exam
    should redirect to
        http://:8080/college/student/exam
    if the url contains query strings it should also get appended in the last

```
ex: http://<myhost>:8080/dev/auth/dev/student/exam?internal=mepa&external=pega
should redirect to
    http://<myhost>:8080/college/student/exam?internal=mepa&external=pega
my url rewrite looks like
        <rule>
        <from>/dev/auth/dev/(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">%{context-path}/college/$1</to>
     </rule>
this is working fine for with out query strings
request you to help - with the rule for with query strings
```

I tried options like - but not working

```
 <rule>
        <condition type="query-string" operator="equal"></condition>
        <from>/dev/auth/dev/(.*)</from>
 <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">%{context-path}/college/$1?%{query-string}</to>
     </rule>
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Hi trevor - i am using Java